# Как сделать поиск по таблице?

Tags: jquery

Есть таблица, я получаю массив в котором названия например "администрация". Они в таблице находятся в td с классом hide-tr. Мне нужно найти в таблице эту строку и вывести все что под ней до следующего td с классом hide-tr.В массиве может быть несколько значений, соответственно нужно несколько значений и выводить несколько . Подскажите как сделать?
Сейчас я делаю массив с названиями и собираю всю таблицу, а вот как дальше я не понимаю.

```
 var a = $("#otd-table table tr").not(".main-head-table"),
            b = [];
            $.each($('.checkbox-otd'),function(index, value){
                if($(this).prop('checked')){
                    b.push(value.value);
                }       
            })



 <table><tr class="main-head-table">
                      <th> текст</th>
                      <th> текст</th>
                      <th> текст</th>
                    </tr><tr>
                      <td colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" class="hide-tr">Администрация</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                      <td> текст</td>
                      <td> текст</td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                      <td> текст</td>
                      <td>тут текст</td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
    <td colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" class="hide-tr">Техники</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                      <td> текст</td>
                      <td> текст</td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                      <td> текст</td>
                      <td>тут текст</td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/974372/256824

Comment: Очень непонятно вопрос задан

Answer (score 0):

Пардон, если вопрос не понял.
Таким образом я создаю таблицу и вывожу данные из БД.
Столбцы идут по очереди, ячейки заполняются тоже по очереди. JobForm - название таблицы, после точки имя столбца. Остаётся только запрос оформить.

```
 <table style="word-wrap: break-word"  border="7">
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Manager</th>
                <th>Car</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Info</th>
                <th>Sistem</th>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="JobForm" items="${optionsList}">

                <tr>
                    <td width="75">${JobForm.workdate}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.manager}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.car}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.client}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.info}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.sistem}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.work}</td>
                    <td width="50"><a href="/options/delete${JobForm.id}">Delete</a></td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
```

Comment: Таблица уже выведена, мне нужно только поиск по ней реализовать

Comment: Тогда запрос, например такой, только указывай что, где и сколько искать. @Query(value = "SELECT count(work) FROM jobform where work = 'Montaz'", nativeQuery = true)
    String getStatistics();